# Spring Set Production / Development level JDBC properties

Tags: spring

I have a JDBC.properties file that contains db connection information

```
jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
jdbc.databaseurl=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/mydb
jdbc.username=root
jdbc.password=
```

Now when I use it in the server my info changes

```
jdbc.username=root
jdbc.password=mypassword
```

What I do now is manually change this information before making war file and upload it to the server.

Now I was wondering if there is any way I could set this information so that i don't have to change this information every time before upload

How to do this??

Comment: Are you using XML configuration or Java @Configuration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't put your properties inside your war file. Externalize them. Put them somewhere in a well known path (/etc/myapp/jdbc.properties).

You shouldn't be creating different artifacts for your production,development and test environment. It should be the same. Recreating the artifact means a new version which (in theory) means new testing. Even if you use maven profiles.

The approach I tend to use is to put some defaults in an internal properties file and optionally load a file from outside the war. That way you provide your users with the possibility to override the default configuration.

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:/jdbc.propertes,file:/etc/myapp/jdbc.properties" igonre-resource-not-found="true" />
```

That way your defaults are inside the application and users can override it by specifying other properties in the `/etc/myapp/jdbc.properties` file.

Comment: Also important is the notion of ordering.  By default, the last file listed takes precedence for any given property, so the above example is in the right order to have the /etc/myapp version to override the classpath version of property settings.  A good thread on this is:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23631399

Answer (score 3):

You could use spring profiles. This blog post should give you the idea: http://spring.io/blog/2011/02/11/spring-framework-3-1-m1-released/

Answer (score 3):

You should use a build tool like Maven and do this with resource filtering and profiles.

Doing it through Spring profiles is probably one way, but in my opinion it makes more sense to be handling it through the build.

Consider the following with Maven:

**src/main/resources/jdbc.properties:**

```
jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
jdbc.databaseurl=${jdbc.databaseurl}
jdbc.username=${jdbc.username}
jdbc.password=${jdbc.password}
```

**pom.xml:**

```
<project ...>
    ...
    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
    ...
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <jdbc.databaseurl>jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/mydb</jdbc.databaseurl>
                <jdbc.username>username</jdbc.username>
                <jdbc.password>password</jdbc.password>
            </properties>
            ...
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>prod</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <jdbc.databaseurl>jdbc:mysql://212.123.45.6/mydb</jdbc.databaseurl>
                <jdbc.username>username</jdbc.username>
                <jdbc.password>secret-password</jdbc.password>
            </properties>
            ...
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    ...
</project>
```

For development, invoke:

```
mvn clean package ... -Pdev
```

Likewise for production:

```
mvn clean package ... -Pprod
```

Maven filtering allows you to replace properties in your `.properties` resources based on properties defined in Maven via `<properties/>` (either in a profile, or not).

References:
- [Resource filtering](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/resource-filtering-sect-description.html)
- [Profiles](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/profiles-sect-activation.html)

Comment: I am using maven. I am new at this. could you please write me some example code?

Comment: The problem with this approach is that you need to recreate your artifacts for every environment. Ideally you should only create your deployable artifact only once and promote it to other servers. Recreation means basically new version, new version means retest.

Comment: There actually is NO problem. With this approach, you could have different jobs for this on your continuous integration server (Jenkins, Hudson, Teamcity, etc) and it will be doing this for you. Your `prod` profile should be `<activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>` and you should be triggering the `-Pdev` only for development.

Comment: What's with the downvote? On your CI server (Jenkins/Hudson/Teamcity/etc) you can have the jobs for the same project but with different profile activations. Win-win. I disagree with the claim that since this will be "a different artifact", it will require more testing. In essence, it's the same artifact, you're just changing a couple of properties for the sake of testing. And yes, the `property-placeholder` is also a nice trick.