# Profiling for different environment Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm working on a maven Spring project, and I'm running Spring 3.0.7

in my .js file i use url for jquery ajax call like following

```
url : "/myProjectName/controllerName/MethodName"
```

In jdbc.properties file my userName & password is like following

```
jdbc.username=root
jdbc.password=
```

and some other like this. this is what i do when I work on my pc. 
But before uploading my application, I have to change these as following

```
url : "/controllerName/MethodName"
jdbc.username=myName
jdbc.password=myPass
```

so what i am doing now is changing this every time manually before uploading my jar in the server.
Now I am wondering if there any way to do this so that I don't have to change this value manually every time before uploading it to the server. I read about profiling I dont know how to use it.

How to do this? Example code is highly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spring Set Production / Development level JDBC properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22196542/spring-set-production-development-level-jdbc-properties)

Comment: Yes that way i have to write 3 different config. I saw in Grails u can do all this in one property file. I am looking something like that

Answer (score 0):

You can add 'profile' attribute to your spring configuration file

Look '**Enter bean definition profiles**' section at [here](http://spring.io/blog/2011/02/11/spring-framework-3-1-m1-released/)

Use below code to set you spring profile, may be you can do this in your ServletContextListener

```
    System.setProperty(AbstractEnvironment.DEFAULT_PROFILES_PROPERTY_NAME, [YOUR PROFILE]);
```

Load both 2 xml file below, only the file match the active profile will effect.

In develop.xml

```
    <beans ... profile="develop">
            ... beans here will only be loaded while profile is 'develop'
    </beans>
```

In server.xml

```
    <beans ... profile="server">
            ... beans here will only be loaded while profile is 'server'
    </beans>
```